# Build failure due to io.selendroid:selendroid-server:0.16.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting below error during build.

```
09:34:21.819 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] Dependency io.selendroid:selendroid-server:0.16.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /Users/{{USERPROFILE}}/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.selendroid/selendroid-server/0.16.0/70cd558cd9dfb5a2a3a3b56713daeca7d79026bf/selendroid-server-0.16.0.apk
09:34:21.819 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] Dependency io.selendroid:android-driver-app:0.16.0 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /Users/{{USERPROFILE}}/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.selendroid/android-driver-app/0.16.0/1e881a13197f9c2f3b10a61a91660816d61b4348/android-driver-app-0.16.0.apk**
```

I have added the dependencies through Maven.

This is how my build.gradle dependencies section looks like:

```
dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'io.selendroid:selendroid-standalone:0.16.0'
compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.2.0'
compile 'io.selendroid:selendroid-client:0.16.0'
}
```

I am trying to trigger appium tests through android studio and the dependencies included are causing build to fail. Do we have any instruction that can be included in build.gradle which tells build to exclude *.apk files and not compile them ?

Additional Info: The stack trace that was included in the build logs

```
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Dependency Error. See console for details.
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.
09:34:21.820 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
09:34:21.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
09:34:21.822 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Dependency Error. See console for details.
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PrepareDependenciesTask.prepare(PrepareDependenciesTask.java:82)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 57 more
09:34:21.823 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: Check this dependency in central maven 'io.selendroid:selendroid-client:0.16.0'.It is an apk. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.selendroid%7Cselendroid-server%7C0.16.0%7Capk

Comment: Thanks for reply Gabriele. Did you mean to refer
    io.selendroid:selendroid-server:0.16.0
as it refers selendroid-server apk.
Nonetheless,  why is it referring to an APK? 
(I am relatively new to Android automation and selendroid. Thus might sound a bit stupid)

Comment: If you check the pom file in the link posted above,you can see: <packaging>apk</packaging>. It is the reason.
You can try to compile 'io.selendroid:selendroid-standalone:0.16.0@jar' in your dependecy but I am not sure that it can work with transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [dependencies](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.selendroid%7Cselendroid-standalone%7C0.16.0%7Cjar) you can see that there are two dependencies with type "apk".

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.selendroid</groupId>
            <artifactId>selendroid-server</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>apk</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.selendroid</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-driver-app</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>apk</type>
        </dependency>
```

You can exclude those dependencies in the following way:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('io.selendroid:selendroid-standalone:0.16.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.selendroid', module: 'selendroid-server'
        exclude group: 'io.selendroid', module: 'android-driver-app'
    }
    compile 'io.selendroid:selendroid-client:0.16.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Blehi. Your snippet worked for me. I downloaded the individual jars for selendroid-server and android-driver-app and included in my project. i no more get the apk related error. However my build is still not successful :(
A line from it (the error message is too big to paste here)
    16:56:01.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"trouble processing \"javax/xml/XMLConstants.class\":","sources":[{}]}    
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

Comment: Hmm ... I don't know what can be the problem. I didn't use this selendroid. I just showed you how to exclude packages that you don't need from a library. Please update your original question and add both the dependencies section of the gradle file and the full stacktrace of the error message. Maybe I can find out what can be the problem.